# Shift array without losing data python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, scipy, interpolation, shift

I have some 3d data arrays, which I want to stack along the 3rd axis. 
I want to stack the cubes such that a data peak in the x-y plane for each cube stacks onto the following peak for the next cube. In order to do so I need to shift each datacube along the x,y plane to align the peak for each cube. However I need a shift that does not cut the data as the usual shift routines appear to do.

A simplified version of want i am looking for would look something like:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = shift(A, 2)  ## shift A 2 steps
b = [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: You can either roll your data with `np.roll` or pad it with [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define `shift` to be the following:

```
def shift(a, k):
    return [0 for _ in range(k)] + a
```

then you get

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = shift(A, 2)
print(b) # [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you wanted shift to be more versatile, you could do

```
def shift(a, k, side=None):
    if shift is None or shift == 'left':
        return [0 for _ in range(k)] + a
    elif shift == 'right':
        return a + [0 for _ in range(k)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to use `numpy` functions. [`np.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) preserves all your data and performs a circular shift:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
np.roll(A,2) #roll 2 places
#array([3, 4, 1, 2])
```

Not exactly what you want, but it does preserve all your data and it's going to be fast.

You can pad your array with [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html), it is going to be slower than `np.roll` but it matches better what you are looking for:

```
np.pad(A,(2,0),mode='constant')
#array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Or to pad with 0s at both ends

```
np.pad(A,(2,3),mode='constant')
#array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0])
```